# Flask-Python traitement of value retunred by empty html input

Tags: python, flask

i'm front of a simple problem but i'm turning arround the right solution... I'm using postgreSQL with Flask for do little web app. So, I have my python code and one template to show you my problem. I have 16 simples HTML input with dataliste from my database traited by my python code, i want to break the treatment of informations at the first empty input encounter. I have done this:

**Template**

```
{% for i in range(16)%} 
        <input type="text"  name="agent{{i}}" list="agent{{i}}" placeholder="Nom, prénom ou matricule ">
            <datalist id="agent{{i}}">
                {% for row in rows %}
                <option value="{{row[0]}};{{row[1]}};{{row[2]}}">Nom:{{row[0]}} Prénom:{{row[1]}} Mat:{{row[2]}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Valider">
```

After, I retrieve the information for processed with this code:

**.py**

```
def after_choix_agent_inscription(error=None):
    print ('Enter in loop')
    for i in range(16):
        test =request.form['agent{}'.format(i)]
        if not (test is None):
            print('Loop n°',i)
            tab = request.form['agent{}'.format(i)].split(';')
            #futur insertion in my database here with data collected
        else:
            print('Break at n°',i-1,'input is empty')
            break
    return render_template('Succes.html')
```

In my exemple i have filled 6 input, so input named "agent6" is empty and return "None" like i have readed? And this is what happen in my console:

```
Loop n° 0
Loop n° 1
Loop n° 2
Loop n° 3
Loop n° 4
Loop n° 5
Loop n° 6
Loop n° 7
Loop n° 8
Loop n° 9
Loop n° 10
Loop n° 11
Loop n° 12
Loop n° 13
Loop n° 14
Loop n° 15
```

At loop 6 it's supposed to be NULL so enter in else: part of the loop ?

Where is my mistake ? Input don't return "None" when empty ? Or my Python loop is bad ( i'm beginner in python like you can see)

Comment: If you're always entering your `if` statement, then obviously the condition `if not (test is None):` is never false.  You're checking if "agent" itself is `None`, not its value, which may in fact be the empty string.  Maybe try comparing it to the empty string instead of `None`?

Comment: check with empty string

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found my mistake thanks to comment of InfiniteHigh. I have one solution, it's not the best but it's works. Values in my input are like this {{X}};{{Y}};{{Z}}, even if my input is empty, his return is not. So i do .split(;) on my returned value and check if X is == at empty string, and it works:

```
    @app.route('/after_choix_agent_inscription', methods=['POST'])
    def after_choix_agent_inscription(error=None):
    print ('Enter in loop')
    for i in range(16):
        reference=""
        test=request.form['agent{}'.format(i)].split(';')
        if not (test[0] == reference):
            print('Loop n°',i) 
        else:
            print('Break after',i-1, 'empty input')
            break
    return render_template('Succes.html')
```

Here, test[0] reference X i'm testing only this one, if is empty others are too.

And it's correctly break after loop 5:

```
Loop n° 0
Loop n° 1
Loop n° 2
Loop n° 3
Loop n° 4
Loop n° 5
Break after 5 empty input
```

If you have protips or a better solution i'm open !